# Why my data from API is not showing when we run iOS app in AWS device farm?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

Our testing team using AWS device farm for testing the android and iOS applications. In my iOS application i am fetching the data from API and displaying it on UI. When i run app on real device and simulators it works fine but using AWS device farm, I am not able to see the data on UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if you ask on the AWS Device Farm forums (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193) as they would be able to help you more thoroughly there. However, based on your description it sounds like there might be a delta between your application that runs locally and the application that gets executed in Device Farm.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. will check it.